# Can anyone help me mimick the style of ltxdockit?

Tags: formatting

First, I'd like you to take a look at the [documentation of the `mathspec` package](http://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/mathspec/mathspec.pdf).
Now I'm not interested in the package as such, but I'd like to use a style like the one used in the documentation.

For instance:

- <del>The short title, subtitle and author section</del>
- <del>two-pane TOC</del>
- <del>all text is indented, things like list numbers and section numbers are "outset" to the left.</del>
- certain keywords (like `\usepackage`) are also outset to the left, while the parameters are indented to the same level as the rest of the text.
- <del>table descriptions, with the nice title, etc.</del>
- the "Advanced" sections, with an extra indentation, or whatever this is.
- <del>line numbers of listings are at the same level as section numbers, while the sourcecode is at the same indentation as the body text.</del>

I know this is rather a lot, but I like this style very much, and I think it would do great on manuals, and general shorter reports/papers.

Stuff like colors, fonts, etc. are no problem for me with XeLaTeX, but getting the keywords indentation right, I can't seem to do that.

---

So far, I've succeeded making the short title with `scrartcl`, and the short and two column TOC with `multitoc`

Making the section numbering be in the margin, I made that with

```
\makeatletter
    \def\@seccntformat#1{\protect\makebox[0pt][r]{\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace{\marglistsep}}}
\makeatother
```

The problem that I try to tackle now, is to have list items appear in the margin as well.
What I mean is exactly like for instance the `\usepackage` item in the PDF. When considering the left margin, I need zero indentation (the content is flush with the left margin), while the item name, is set to the left inside the margin, and ends just at the end of the left margin - I hope this is descriptive enough.

the `listings` package predefines line numbers in margins, so that was rather easy to achieve.

Getting the "nice" table as it is defined in `ltxdockit` was rather complicated:
Using the packages `caption` and `booktabs`, as well as `floatrow`:

```
\DeclareCaptionFont{spot}{\color{spot}}

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{enskip}{\enskip}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{lc}{\MakeLowercase{#1}~\MakeLowercase{#2}}

\captionsetup{
    font=small,
    labelformat=lc,
    labelfont={sc,bf,spot},
    labelsep=enskip,
    indention=0pt,
    format=plain,
}
```

*(color "spot" must be defined further above in this example)*

The table itself must be made like this:

```
\begin{table}[h] \centering
\ttabbox{
    \caption{this is the caption\label{tab:cap}}
}{
    \begin{tabular}
        ...
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is. Anyway, `etoolbox` and `csquotes` use it too. The best thing to start using it is looking to the source of the documentation of those packages and see how everything works. By the way, it's also available through a [package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ltxdockit).

Comment: have you looked at the `mathspec.tex`: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/xetex/latex/mathspec/mathspec.tex

Comment: @cmhughes Indeed I have, and that's where my problem comes from: it uses `ltxdockit` which is not supposed to be used for anything other than TeX documentation. It kinda makes sense, since the implementation is almost comically crude, and offers close to no flexibility. Hence, I want something that looks like that, but isn't `ltxdockit`.

Comment: It isn't supported and it is designed to typeset documentation but there is nothing to stop you from using it or from using it as the basis for a more flexible class. (It is LPPL, after all.) Also, the file @cmhughes linked to contains stuff which doesn't depend on that class and which your question explicitly mentions wanting. So start with that and dip into the class as necessary. Then post a more specific question with the code you come up with. Right now, you are basically asking somebody to write a class but questions on this site should be answerable in a 'few paragraphs' ;).

Comment: I think you would be better off asking separate questions about the individual points.

Comment: @AndrewSwann yeah, I wanted to avoid just that, actually